# Matlab Vector to xls

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `V` with a single row and 16761 columns.

I want to write it to an `XLS` file to use it for training of neural network.

I have tried following code but I got error:

```
V = reshape(I,1,16761);
filename = 'testdata.xls';
xlswrite(filename,V);`
```

Please help me to come out-off it.

Comment: A simpler way to transpose `I` would be `I'`. Are you sure you named your vector `I` and not just `V`. Also, in general, it is always helpful to show the error message you came across.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Thanks ... I got my answer, It was due to large size of vector, Excel supports only 256 columns

Comment: @yagyavrat, SO is only as useful as its answers. Please do one of two things: Delete this question, or update the question with the error message and then write up the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by the asker:

> It was due to large size of vector, Excel supports only 256 columns

Note that versions after Excel 2003 support upto 16384 columns.

Comment: Actually this is only valid till excel 2003 ( http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_rows_and_columns_are_there_in_Excel ) - excel 2007 supports up to 16,384 columns.

Comment: @bdecaf Thanks, Have improved the answers.

Comment: Just for completeness - to have Matlab produce a file in the "new" format you need to specify the ".xlsx" extension.